# Добавление видео с youtube для вконтакте (с помощью jQuery или javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Не получается добавить видео с помощью ссылки ютуба для вконтакте (в автомат режиме, с помощью javascript или jQuery).
Добавил код ссылки ютуба в нужное место (страница Видеозаписи вконтакте):

```
jQuery("input#video_external_link").val("ссылка видео ютуба");
```

или с яваскриптом:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input#video_external_link")[0].value = "ссылка видео ютуба"
```

Но ничего не происходит, должна была выйти вся подробная информация о видео ютуба (с кнопкой добавления вконтакте), которую хочу добавить.

Пробовал `jQuery("body *").focus().blur();` — работает только если мышка в фокусе в текущем браузере, а если находится вне браузера, то опять ничего не происходит, хочу чтобы всегда работал.

Вот пример, как происходит:

Если вручную:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если с помощью яваскрипта:

Код:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По последнему скриншоту видно что не реагирует на ссылку, которую ставили с помощью кода. 
Чего здесь не хватает, чтобы все заработало?

Answer (score 4):

У меня вот так работает

```
const el = document.querySelector('#video_external_link');
el.value = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RbESB3qHWOw';
triggerEvent(el, 'blur');
```

Answer (score 4):

Так работает

```
var vid = document.getElementById("video_external_link");//получаем элемент
vid.value = "ссылка";//записываем ссылку
var foc = new Event("focus");// содаем событие фокус
var bl = new Event("blur"); // создаем событие блюр
vid.dispatchEvent(foc); //фокусим input
vid.dispatchEvent(bl); //вызываем событие blur
```